# Error Using PHP Class <b>Notice</b>: Undefined property

Tags: php, actionscript-3, class

I am still a newby with PHP.  I have a flash file that passes some variables to a php script and creates a zip file of a group of jpg files.  When I had all of the code in one php file everything worked fine.  Now I wanted to separate out the script into two files.  One php file that gets the variables and a class that would actually do the work of creating the file.  However I am getting this error when I run it.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: ZipTestClass::$FileName.zip in <b>F:\Web Page      mcwphoto43\TestZip\Array\ZipTestClass.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
```

**Here is my original code which worked just fine**

```
<?PHP
//stores the URLvariables into variables that php can use
$img1 = $_GET['Image1']; 
$img2 = $_GET['Image2']; 
$img3= $_GET['Image3'];
$zipName= $_GET['Name'];

// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

// open archive 
if ($zip->open($zipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
die ("Could not open archive");
}

// list of files to add
$fileList = array(
'ZipTest/' . $img1,
'ZipTest/' . $img2,
'ZipTest/' . $img3
);

// add files
foreach ($fileList as $f) {
$zip->addFile($f) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $f");  
}

// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";   
?>
```

**Here is the first part of my new code which brings in the variables and calls the class**

```
<?PHP

//stores the URLvariables into variables that php can use
$Img1 = $_GET['Image1']; 
$Img2 = $_GET['Image2']; 
$Img3= $_GET['Image3'];
$zipName= $_GET['Name'];
//$RandVariable = $_GET['randString'];

echo "Variables $Img1, $Img2, $Img3, $zipName were accepted."; 

//Brings in ZipTestClass, creates an instance of the class as a variable, assgns values to the class
include "ZipTestClass.php";

$OrderInfo = new ZipTestClass;

$OrderInfo->img1 = "$Img1";
$OrderInfo->img2 = "$Img2";
$OrderInfo->img3 = "$Img3";
$OrderInfo->zipName = "$zipName";
$OrderInfo->CreateZip($Img1,$Img2,$Img3,$zipName);

?>
```

**Here is the class**

```
<?PHP
class ZipTestClass{

//Receivers of the URLvariables needed to create the sip file based on the customers     order
var $img1;
var $img2;
var $img3;
var $zipName;
var $zip;

public function CreateZip($img1, $img2, $img3, $zipName)
{
    // create object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $fileArchive = $this->$zipName;

    // open archive 
    if ($zip->open('Work', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) 
    {
        die ("Could not open archive");
    }


    // list of files to add
    $fileList = array('ZipTest/' . $this->$img1, 'ZipTest/' . $this->$img2,     'ZipTest/' . $this->$img3);

    // add files
    foreach ($fileList as $f) 
    {
        $zip->addFile($f) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $f");   
    }

    // close and save archive
    $zip->close();
    echo "Archive created successfully."; 
}
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `$this->$zipName` should be `$this->zipName`

Answer (score 7):

Simple: change `$fileArchive = $this->$zipName;` to `$fileArchive = $this->zipName;`. The error message points you to exactly what to do. What you were doing is called variable variables, trying to use the value of the parameter $zipname as the property name.

edit:

A second look at your code shows that you missed some of the point. You don't need to pass any of those parameters to `CreateZip` - you aren't even using them. You already set all the necessary variables beforehand (by the way, that's a bad practice, reaching into your class and modifying its member variables like that). So you could either remove the method parameters, or remove the lines setting the values before you call CreateZip, and use the parameters in the method instead of the class members.

edit 2:

You have the same issue going on later in the method, with things like `$this->$img1`.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing the field incorrectly:

```
// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileArchive = $this->$zipName;
```

Should be:

```
// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileArchive = $this->zipName;
```

When you put a dollar sign in front of a property name, PHP looks for a property on the class that is named after the *contents of the variable with that name*.

So, as we can see from your error message, the contents of `$zipName` is 'FileName.zip' - but there is no property on the class called 'FileName.zip'.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function CreateZip($img1, $img2, $img3, $zipName) {
   $this->$zipName;
   //code
}
```

The above is not doing what you intended to do. What you're actually doing there is telling your class to look for a member property with the text value of `$zipName`.

So a call like

```
CreateZip('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'myzipfile.zip');
```

Will make your script look for `$this->myzipfile.zip`, which obviously doesn't exist. Simply replacing `$this->$zipName;` with `$this->zipName;` will fix your problem.

**This holds true for the rest of your variables too `$this->$img1` and `$this->$img2`**